# Is it possible to capture images without showing camera?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to capture images without showing the camera. But no matter what I've done I got the screen shown below. How can I hide the live camera?[image]`

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Have you tried putting a UIView in front of it, or just putting it to the back.

Comment: So you don't want to show the camera picker? Or that you don't want the camera picker interface?